# Pandas groupby and aggregate: produce unique single values for some cells

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

All,

I have the following pd.DataFrame():

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'fruit': ['carrot','carrot','apple','apple', 'tomato'],
                   'taste': ['sweet','sweet','sweet','bitter','bitter'],
                   'quality': ['good','poor','rotten','good','good']})
```

Which looks like this:

```
    fruit   taste quality
0  carrot   sweet    good
1  carrot   sweet    poor
2   apple   sweet  rotten
3   apple  bitter    good
4  tomato  bitter    good
```

I apply grouby and agg like this:

```
df.groupby('fruit').agg(pd.Series.tolist)
```

producing:

```
                  taste         quality
fruit                                  
apple   [sweet, bitter]  [rotten, good]
carrot   [sweet, sweet]    [good, poor]
tomato         [bitter]          [good]
```

But what I want is:

```
                  taste         quality
fruit                                  
apple   [sweet, bitter]  [rotten, good]
carrot            sweet    [good, poor]
tomato           bitter            good
```

In words: I want to only aggregate the entries that have multiple different values, but when the list only contains the same unique item, I want it to just contain said item. Is there a nice way of doing this (preferable by not going through all cells of the df, mine is rather big, but perhaps it is the only way?)? Apologies if I'm unclear, I struggle to express this in words (hence the difficult title also).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the rationale between having different datatypes... eg: sometimes a string, sometimes a list... that doesn't seem particularly usable...

Comment: I want to write the dataframe.groupby to postgres, so I can't have lists. This way I can "collapse" the dataframe, then remove all columns with lists and start working on a better way to link to tables that have the values that are lists as separate table. Basically I was looking for the values that are not changing per "fruit". Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom lambda function for remove duplicates by `set`s with convert unique values to scalars:

```
f = lambda x: list(set(x)) if len(set(x)) > 1 else x.iat[0]
df = df.groupby('fruit').agg(f)
print (df)
                  taste         quality
fruit                                  
apple   [sweet, bitter]  [rotten, good]
carrot            sweet    [poor, good]
tomato           bitter            good
```

If ordering is important:

```
f = lambda x: list(dict.fromkeys(x)) if len(set(x)) > 1 else x.iat[0]
df = df.groupby('fruit').agg(f)
print (df)
                  taste         quality
fruit                                  
apple   [sweet, bitter]  [rotten, good]
carrot            sweet    [good, poor]
tomato           bitter            good
```

Comment: Ok, yeah this works and seems to about as fast as without the lambda function. Thanx!